# Why when I use the method click () , the result is repeated?

Tags: jquery, object, button, methods, click

First, I have to say that this happens when I add dynamic rows to a dynamic table.

In the method `datosGuardados` I have the object I want to show for Chrome's debug console.

```
datosGuardados: function(problema){

var self  = this;

var objTareas = new Object();

objTareas.tareas = aTareas;
objTareas.descripcionProblema = problema;
objTareas.idTareaSeleccionada = $('#nombre_trabajador_id').val();
objTareas.nombreTrabajador = $('#nombre_trabajador_id option:selected').text();

console.info(objTareas);
return objTareas;    },
```

And this is the method `AccionBotonEnviar` that contains the button:

```
AccionBotonEnviar: function(data){

var self = this;      
$("#btn_enviar_formulario_id").click(function(){

    self.datosGuardados();

}); },
```

If I add a row in the table and I print without using the button , it shows me :

```
Object {tareas: Array[2], descripcionProblema: "aaa", idTareaSeleccionada: "2", nombreTrabajador: "Trabajador 2"}
```

But using the button print:

```
Object {tareas: Array[2], descripcionProblema: "aaa", idTareaSeleccionada: "2", nombreTrabajador: "Trabajador 2"}
Object {tareas: Array[2], descripcionProblema: "aaa", idTareaSeleccionada: "2", nombreTrabajador: "Trabajador 2"}
```

TWICE...

And If I add two rows , and press the button , print three..

What is the problem?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are binding the same click handler again and again.  Hack fix is `$("#btn_enviar_formulario_id").off('click').click(function(){` but you really should find the root of problem where the function is being called again

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks . But you say that the problem is something else?

Comment: yes, you are calling the same function when you aren't expecting to ( or need to). Probably in the add row method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you are calling the function again that is binding a new click handler again and again. probably in the method that adds new rows.

You can unbind the existing one using:

```
$("#btn_enviar_formulario_id").off('click').click(function(){
      self.datosGuardados();
});
```

but since it is not needed to repeatedly call the function you probably need to remove it from wherever it is being called again

Comment: Thanks ! , anyway is strange because in this module , I'm not calling the function again. But i will check again.